# Which version of SVM to run in Weka?

Tags: weka, svm, libsvm

I need to use Weka's LibSVM implementation of SVM classifers on frequencies of keywords in RSS feeds to classify the feeds into target categories. But I'm not sure which version to run given my data.

My .arff files typically contains the following data:

```
@attribute Keyword_1_nasa_Frequency numeric
@attribute Keyword_2_fish_Frequency numeric
@attribute Keyword_3_kill_Frequency numeric
@attribute Keyword_4_show_Frequency numeric
…
@attribute RSSFeedCategoryDescription {BFE,FCL,F,M, NCA, SNT,S}

@data
0,0,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,BFE
…
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,FCL
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F
…
20,0,64,19,0,162,0,0,36,72,179,24,24,47,24,40,0,48,0,0,0,97,24,0,48,205,143,62,7
8,0,0,216,0,36,24,24,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,140,24,0,0,0,0,72,176,0,0,144,48,0,38,0,284,
221,72,0,72,0,SNT
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,SNT
0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,S
```

And so on: there’s a total of 570 rows where each one is contains with the 
frequency of a keyword in a feed for a day. In this case, there are 57 feeds for 
10 days giving a total of 570 records to be classified. Each keyword is prefixed 
with a surrogate number and postfixed with ‘Frequency’.

But in other cases, I have used boolean values for frequencies, so that the first line of the above is:

false,false,false,true,false...,BFE

And so on, where 34 is true because a threshold is met, and the others are false because the threshold is not met.

According to what I can determine, there are three types of SVM in Weka, but can anybody tell me which type(s) I should be using with my data above?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying with all three kernel types and determining which one is the best to suit your training and validation data (do a plot) and then just keep using that training model to predict new inputs.

In weka you can save your model for future use.